# error when pip install google-colab --use-pep517

Tags: python, pip, google-colaboratory

i got this error:

Collecting pandas~=0.24.0 (from google-colab)
Using cached pandas-0.24.2.tar.gz (11.8 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Installing backend dependencies ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [4 lines of output]
:12: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
error in pandas setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Expected end or semicolon (after version specifier)
pytz >= 2011k
~~~~~~~^
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

Comment: What version of python are you running in colab? pandas 0.24 is quite old and seems to only support python 3.7 and lower

Answer (score 0):

Seems like PyPI hosts some old version. See also https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/2598

I used the following command to install directly from source:

```
  pip install -e git+https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools#egg=google.colab
```

Be warned that google.colab requires quite old package versions on its dependencies even when installed from source. So using virtualenv is recommended here.